# LinkedList - Static Code Analysis - Iterating via index

Tags: java, performance, linked-list, iterator, static-code-analysis

Are there any static code analyzers out there which are able to detect if code uses an instance of java.util.List, implemented by java.util.LinkedList and iterates through it via index (instead of java.util.Iterator) causing bad performance?

e.g.

```
List list = new LinkedList();

// populate list ...

for(int ii=0; ii<list.size(); ii++) {
}
```

Checked findbugs, spotbugs, huntbugs, google error-prone, pmd, but no luck so far.

Comment: Hmmm ...  no. For obvious reasons.

Comment: @MickMnemonic what's your question?

Comment: I don't think that you can find such analyzer with this functionality out of the box , but, I believe, you can configure such detection rule, for example in Fortify.

Comment: You could write an errorprone check which finds calls to `LinkedList.get` in a loop whose guard contains a call to `LinkedList.size()`. But note that this doesn't really fall within the scope of the standard errorprone release because it doesn't represent a correctness issue.

Comment: @MickMnemonic it's not a `foreach` loop, it's a loop _by index_. It should be obvious why this has quadratic performance for a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Thanks, all for your comments. As noted there, random (index) access via #get(int) or #remove(int) as outlined in my sample has O(n) whereas iterating via iterator/for each has O(1). Having skimmed over google error prone, it seems that it is possible to detect such cases. We will be looking into that and update this stackoverflow should we find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

here's the link to discussion / patch on google error prone github

https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/762